# Send Kendo Grid Data to Web API Method

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, asp.net-web-api2, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid, which is populated from a remote API.

When I click the 'Save Changes' button on the UI, I want it to pass the data model to the API.

However, in my code below in the **Update** statement, I get a "*JavaScript runtime error: Expected ';'*" error. 
However, I can't see what is causing this error.

Any idea what I am missing here so that I can pass the grid data to the API?

```
var crudServiceBaseUrl = apiurl + "calendar/",
    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/GetCalendars",
                dataType: "json" // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
            },
            update: function (myData) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/UpdateCalendar",
                                dataType: "json",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {
                                    models: JSON.stringify(myData.data.models)                                     
                                }
                            });
            },
            destroy: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            },
            create: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },
        batch: true,
        //pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "CalendarName",
                fields: {
                    CalendarName: { editable: true, nullable: false },
                    Monday: { type: "boolean" },
                    Tuesday: { type: "boolean" },
                    Wednesday: { type: "boolean" },
                    Thursday: { type: "boolean" },
                    Friday: { type: "boolean" },
                    Saturday: { type: "boolean" },
                    Sunday: { type: "boolean" }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing brace on the data object:

```
data: {
    models: JSON.stringify(myData.data.models)
}
```

Hopefully that's all you need to add.